# Centos cURL connection refused on Its own IP

Tags: centos, curl, loopback

I have two services on one server (with different ports to access them).

One of my services is trying to connect to the other one with the IP of server and its specific port. But I got some errors about `Connection refused myip`.
Then I checked the command `curl -v myip:myport` and got the following error:

`* About to connect() to myip port myport (#0)`

`*   Trying myip... Connection refused`

`* couldn't connect to host`

`* Closing connection #0`

`curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

but when I executed `curl -v 127.0.0.1`, I got correct response.

I even executed `curl -v myip:myport` on some other server and got correct response.

I think something about loopback doesn't work well on my server. Any one has any idea how should I fix it??

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the loopback address of 127.0.0.1 when communicating on the same server?  That is what it is for after all.

Comment: @Paul Yes, the services are completely separate from each other. And they don't know they are running on the same server. So I should use the network IP instead of using local IP for more generality.

Comment: Are you running iptables on the server?

Comment: @Paul Yes, but I stopped iptables and it doesn't help!